# Fetching Emails of Companies whose Products are in the Shopping Cart

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to get **Emails** of Companies whose products are in the **Shopping Cart**.

Till Yet, I wrote Below Query , But It's is not fetching me Emails Of Companies.

Kindly Help.

```
SELECT distinct c.u_email FROM products as p INNER JOIN companies as c ON p.u_id = c.u_id WHERE p.u_id IN ($cart_product_ids)
```

In Above Query $cart_product_ids can be like 11 Or 11,13 etc .....
This is a Table named **companies**

[image: Table Of reg_companies]

This is a Table named **products**

[image]

This is a Table named **requested_products**

[image]

Comment: what is this 
$cart_product_ids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming this  $cart_product_ids='1,2,3' like value

`WHERE p.u_id IN ($cart_product_ids)`

you have write `u_id` here.

if  you have yo `u_id`  you can directly use it with user table.

**But**  I think you have here **`product ID`** so you need to change you where condition

**`WHERE p.p_id IN ($cart_product_ids)`**

Answer (score 0):

If $cart_product_ids is being passed as an array you will want to implode the ids using `implode(', ', $cart_product_ids)`

Otherwise try a LEFT JOIN and select from the company table:

`SELECT distinct c.u_email FROM company as c LEFT JOIN products as p ON p.u_id = c.u_id WHERE p.u_id IN ($cart_product_ids)`